# List xml nodes and attribute name from xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

How to retreive node_names and attribute_names from a xml (not values of node or attributes) Is it possible using jquery?

```
<Client>
    <product name="astro">
        <service_process name="ACID">
            <host>pable</host>
            <port>18848</port>
        </servcice_process>
        <service_process name="Mestro">
            <host>Mico</host>
            <port>18821</port>
        </servcice_process>
    </product>
</Client>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start with something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/74avm/1/):

```
var xml = '<Client><product name="astro"><service_process name="ACID"><host>pable</host><port>18848</port></servcice_process><service_process name="Mestro"><host>Mico</host><port>18821</port></servcice_process></product></Client>';

$(xml).each(function displayChildren (i, node) {
  console.log(node.nodeName);

  // traverse attributes
  $.each(node.attributes, function (j, attr) {
    console.log(attr.nodeName, attr.nodeValue);
  });

  // recursive call
  $(node).children().each(displayChildren);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick search revealed [this page](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery) which deals in XML Parsing with jQuery. Getting the node name is a little more difficult but a method for getting it is provided [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-how-to-get-the-tag-name/). From a quick look, I'm assuming you'd want to do something along the lines of:

```
$(xml).each(function(){ //xml is the XML resource.
  if($(this).attr("name")!=""){
    alert("Name = " + $(this).attr("name"));
  }
  alert("Node = " + $(this).get(0).TagName);
});
```

I believe this should work no problems.